# Can't find module @angular/core...even after installing dependencies in Angular 4 quickstart

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I have downloaded Quickstart Project of Angular 4.3.1 from Angular website (angular.io)

But Getting error, can't find module @angular/core, even after loading dependencies

I think Angular cli is not able to locate node_modules folder. what should I do?

[Here is error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyCkA.png)

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes...I fired that command...but still getting same error